# how to track the data from the scene SpriteKit without NSNotificationCenter

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, nsnotificationcenter

I need to track for data from `SpriteKit` scene. I made it with help `NSNotificationCenter`. It works for me.

There is evidence that I have to withdraw from the scene. And put them in Label, I did change data capture by using the `NSNotificationCenter`, but I was told you can not do. That is, I did by using the `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSUserDefaults` But I need to make it by differently.

I don't know how can I make it?

Comment: NSUserDefaults, userData property which every node has, custom property on a scene, global struct, singleton ... You have to be more specific and add more context to your question.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to pass some values from one scene to another? Also, are you interested in persistence of those values  accros multiple app launches?

Comment: @Whirlwind No. I want to save this data even after reload device. But I need some data from SpriteKit and to insert these data in UILabel

Comment: @Whirlwind But I cannot to use NSNotificationCenter and NSUserDefaults for it.

Comment: @Alexander Using NSUserDefaults would be an easiest solution. Based on type and amount of data, and how you are planning to use that data, you can choose between plist files, CoreData, NSCoding protocol, Sqlite, iCloud...

Comment: @Whirlwind Yes, I know about NSUserDefaults, but team lead told to me that I cannot to use NSUserDefaults or NSNotificationCenter

Comment: if the data is not large, you could also store it in the keychain, that is if you have data that you need protected and do not want anybody to access outside of the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it with help of `NSUserDefaults`